# Rectangular to polar form using exact values.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm in a first year math course at university, and we've been asked to convert a rectangular form complex number into polar form, using exact values only.

I have the modulus, that's all good. But I now have $\tan\theta=2-\sqrt{3}$ for the argument. I plugged this into my calculator and it spat out $15^{\circ}$ which I know can be represented as $\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}$ but I can't for the life of me figure out how we are supposed to be able to get from $\tan\theta=2-\sqrt{3}$ to $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}$ without using a calculator!

Am I missing some elementary step? Many thanks.

Comment: You need not. Use a calculator as much as you like to get from $2-\sqrt{3}$ to $\frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4}$. As long as you can do the other direction without a calculator, you're home.

Comment: True. I'm just concerned about the strict instruction in the question which says "no calculators please!"

Comment: You could use the approximation $\tan \theta \approx \theta$ for small $\lvert\theta\rvert$, and the assumption that the angle will likely be some nice rational multiple of $\pi$ to guess $\frac{\pi}{12}$, and then check it.

Comment: Another option is the double-angle formula. $$\tan (2\theta) = \frac{2\tan \theta}{1 + \tan^2\theta} = \frac{4-2\sqrt{3}}{1 + 7-4\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: You are right, there is no obvious structural difference between $x$ such that $\arctan x$ (or $\arcsin x$) is a rational multiple of $\pi$, and those for which it isn't.

Comment: You can solve this easily in a direct fashion, no tricks involved. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Apply the identity $\tan(A-B) = \dfrac{\tan A - \tan B}{1 + \tan A \tan B}$ as follows:

$\tan 15^{\circ} = \tan(60^{\circ}-45^{\circ}) = \dfrac{\tan 60^{\circ} - \tan 45^{\circ}}{1 + \tan 60^{\circ} \tan 45^{\circ}}$.

Can you continue from here?

Note that you could also use any pair $A,B$ such that $A-B = 15^{\circ}$, however, you want to stick to $A,B$ such that you know the values of $\tan A$ and $\tan B$. One such pair is $(A,B) = (60^{\circ},45^{\circ})$. Another pair you could have used is $(A,B) = (45^{\circ},30^{\circ})$.

Comment: This helps. While there isn't really a visible step between $\text{tan}\theta=2-\sqrt{3}$ and this, I'll see if I can use it. Thank you :)

Comment: Part of learning trigonometry involves memorizing trig values at multiples of $15^{\circ}$. You probably have $\sin \theta$, $\cos \theta$, and $\tan \theta$ memorized at $0^{\circ}$, $30^{\circ}$, $45^{\circ}$, $60^{\circ}$, and $90^{\circ}$. So what's wrong with knowing the values at $15^{\circ}$ and $75^{\circ}$?

Comment: Nothing. It's just been a very long time since high school maths. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this equation exactly. Note that you can write
$$
\tan t =\frac{\sin t}{\cos t} = \frac{\frac{1}{2i}(e^{it}-e^{-it})}{\frac12(e^{it}+e^{-it})}=\frac 1i\frac{e^{2it}-1}{e^{2it}+1}
$$

Now suppose we are given $w$ (in your case,  $w=2-\sqrt 3$); to solve
$$w=\tan t$$ we use the expression above to write

$$w = \frac 1i\frac{e^{2it}-1}{e^{2it}+1}$$
$$iw(e^{2it}+1) = e^{2it}-1$$
$$e^{2it}(1-iw) =1+iw$$
$$e^{2it}=\frac{1+iw}{1-iw}$$
Using your particular value $w=2-\sqrt 3$, the expression $\frac{1+iw}{1-iw}$ simplifies after some tedious basic arithmetic to $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\frac12 i  =e^{\pi i/6}$. Our equation, therefore, is

$$e^{2it} =e^{\pi i/6}$$
which means
$$2it = \frac{\pi}{6}i +2\pi ki$$
$$\boxed{t =\dfrac{\pi}{12} + \pi k}$$
for integral $k$, as desired.